# Complex derived attributes in Django models

Tags: sql, django, django-models, sql-update, user-defined-functions

What I want to do is implement submission scoring for a site with users voting on the content, much like in e.g. reddit (see the 'hot' function in http://code.reddit.com/browser/sql/functions.sql).  **Edit:**  Ultimately I want to be able to retrieve an arbitrarily filtered list of arbitrary length of submissions ranked according to their score.

My submission model currently keeps track of up and down vote totals.  Currently, when a user votes I create and save a related Vote object and then use F() expressions to update the Submission object's voting totals.  The problem is that I want to update the score for the submission at the same time, but F() expressions are limited to only simple operations (it's missing support for log(), date_part(), sign() etc.)

From my limited experience with Django I can see 5 options here:

1. extend F() somehow (haven't looked at the code yet) to support the missing SQL functions;  this is my preferred option and seems to fit within the Django framework the best
2. define a scoring function (much like reddit's 'hot' function) in my database, and have Django use the value of that function for the value of the score field;  as far as I can tell, #2 is not possible
3. wrap my two step voting process in a suitably isolated transaction so that I can calculate the voting totals in Python and then update the Submission's voting totals without fear that another vote against the submission could be added/changed in the meantime;  I'm hesitant to take this route because it seems overly complex - what is a "suitably isolated transaction" in this case anyway?
4. use raw SQL;  I would prefer to avoid this entirely -- what's the point of an ORM if I have to revert to SQL for such a common use case as this!  (Note that this coming from somebody who loves sprocs, but is using Django for ease of development.)
5. **(edit: added this after further discussion)** compute the score using an extra select parameter containing a call to my function;  this would work but impose unnecessary load on the DB (would be forced to calculate the score for every submission ever made every time the query ran;  caching could help here, but it still seems like a bit of lame workaround)

Before I embark on this mission to extend F() (which I'm not sure is even possible), am I about to reinvent the wheel?  Is there a more standard way to do this?  It seems like such a common use case and yet in an hour of searching I have yet to find a common solution...

**EDIT**:  There is another option:  set the default value of the field in the database script to be an expression containing my function.  This is not as flexible as #1, but probably the quickest and cleanest approach to solving the problem (although my initial investigation into extending F() looks promising).

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just denormalize the score and reconstruct it with the Vote objects every once and a while?

If you can't do that, it is very easy to make a 'property' function that acts as an object attribute for scoring.

```
@property
def score(self):
    ... calculate score from Vote objects ...
    return score
```

I've never used F() on a property like this, but it's Python, so I bet it works.

If you are using django-voting (which I recommend), you can put #3 in the manager's record_vote function since that's how all vote transactions take place.

Comment: While it's true I could denormalise as you say, this to me is a very basic use case of DBMSs and if Django doesn't support it then I would at least like to make an effort to add my own support for it, time and simplifications permitting (no multi-DB compatibility for instance). The basic work is there in the F() expressions.

Derived Pythonic properties won't work;  sorry, I left out a requirement:  I want to be able to retrieve a list of popular submissions with arbitrary categories, tags, etc.

Django-voting is nice but I would prefer to avoid option #3 as it is ultimately a workaround.